# Insert XML data in one of two data table according to Xml attribute value.

Tags: c#

> I have 2 datatables fireCollarTable_ and electrofusionTable_.

```
        fireCollarTable_ = new System.Data.DataTable("Fire Collar");
        fireCollarTable_.Columns.Add("Article", typeof(string));
        fireCollarTable_.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
        fireCollarTable_.Columns.Add("Diameter", typeof(double));

        electroFusionCouplerTable_ = new System.Data.DataTable("Electrofusion Coupler");
        electroFusionCouplerTable_.Columns.Add("Article", typeof(string));
        electroFusionCouplerTable_.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
        electroFusionCouplerTable_.Columns.Add("Diameter", typeof(double));
        electroFusionCouplerTable_.Columns.Add("Length", typeof(double));
```

> the above two datatables are defined,the XML file is

```
   <Catalogue>

     <!--  1-Item, 2-Article, 3-Description, 4-PipeType, 5-Diameter -->

     <Record a1="Fire Collar" a2="VS0410001" a3="Fire Collar, 40 mm" a5="40" />
     <Record a1="Fire Collar" a2="VS0410003" a3="Fire Collar, 50 mm" a5="50" />
     <Record a1="Fire Collar" a2="VS0410005" a3="Fire Collar, 56 mm" a5="56" />

     <!--  1-Item, 2-Article, 3-Description, 4-PipeType, 5-Diameter,9-Length-->

     <Record a1="Electrofusion Coupler" a2="VS0350001" a3="Electrofusion coupler, 40 mm"         a5="40" a9="64" />
     <Record a1="Electrofusion Coupler" a2="VS0350003" a3="Electrofusion coupler, 50 mm" a5="50" a9="60" />

   </Catalogue>
```

I want to parse the XML file and according to value of attribute "a1",i want to insert data into one of datatables. e.g.  if value of "a1" = "Fire Collar" then data should be inserted in firecollar table.

Answer (score 1):

You should use XPath for parsing XML file in C#. Follow this link "http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333" and "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/52079/Using-XPathNavigator-in-C#". 
I am giving you an example here:

1. Load the xml file in XmlDocument using XmlDocument.Load("abc.xml");
2. query using XmlDocument.SelecteNodes("//Records[@a=""]");

you can search the particular node with a parameter and place XmlNode.Value whereever it is required to be placed.

Search this on Google you will get exact syntax and flow.

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Load(@"\XMLFile1.xml");

        XmlNodeList fireCollarNodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/Catalogue/Record[@a1='Fire Collar']");

        foreach (XmlNode fireCollarNode in fireCollarNodeList)
        {
            // add details to the fireCollarTable_
        }

        XmlNodeList electroFusionCouplerNodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/Catalogue/Record[@a1='Electrofusion Coupler']");

        foreach (XmlNode fireCollarNode in fireCollarNodeList)
        {
            // add details to the electroFusionCouplerTable_
        }
```